# Using background-position with percentages for image sprites

Tags: html, css, css-sprites

I'm trying to use the `background-position` property with percentages in an image sprite. It doesn't seem to work though i.e. it doesn't shift the background-image.

You can see an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/3UQYg/3/

When I use pixels, then the image does shift: See here http://jsfiddle.net/3UQYg/2/.

What am I doing wrong?!

Comment: See: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/994-CSS-Background-Images-Using-Percentage-Positioning.htm

Comment: @Diodeus Thanks. It turns out with `background-position` in percentages it works in a new 'non-intuitive' way #bummer. I'll have to try something else.

Answer (score 8):

### background-position: x% y%;

Actually, the percent background-position works like this:

[image]

- When **abscissa** is `0%`, then image's left side aligns container's left side.
- When **abscissa** is `100%`, then image's right side aligns with container's right side.
- Intermediate values are calculated linearly.

Similarly,

- When **ordinate** is `0%`, then image's top side aligns container's top side.
- When **ordinate** is `100%`, then image's bottom side aligns with container's bottom.
- Intermediate values are calculated linearly.

---

Answer (score 0):

Exactly.

Pixels don't work the same way than percentage in background-position. As a summary: background-position:30% 10% for example will align the point located at 30% 10% of your image with the 30% 10% axis of your cointaining DIV or HTML tag. Being not so obvious to calculate the percentage number.

Next article explains it all:
http://www.sitepoint.com/css-using-percentages-in-background-image/